# Cannot execute script outside of home directory

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, permissions, scripts

I have a hard drive mounted as /data. I'm the owner of the mountpoint, and I own all the directories under it. I installed an IDE under /data. It contains a shell script you need to execute to setup the IDE. This file is also owned by me, and is user, group, world executable. (i.e. I don't need chmod +x ...). For some reason, it wont let me execute the script. I continually get permission denied errors. As soon as I move the file to my home directory, with no permissions changes, it lets me execute the script. Is there a setting somewhere that is preventing me from executing files outside of my home directory, even if I own them and they are set as executable?

In case it matters, I'm running 16.04.

Comment: *How* is the drive mounted? what are its mount options (check by running the `mount` command with no arguments)

Comment: also, please [edit] your question with the output of `ls -lsa /data/your-shell-script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

baAmong the options you can pass to `mount` or write in `fstab` there is an `exec` flag. Remounting your drive with that option should help.

(If this is a `bash` script, you can probably also do `/bin/bash /data/nameOfScript`, but you'll run into the next problems soon, I guess.)

Comment: thanks. Thats what it was. I didn't realize the default was noexec, I thought you had to specify that explicitly and that the default was exec